# URL works on Browser but with VBA throws HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to retrieve data from ClearQuest server in XML format. I have VBA code which fetches data from server and put that in Excel. The code was working fine till last week.

Now if I run the code, I get "Internal Server Error" message. and If I use the same URL on browser, I get the correct result.

The VBA code I am using is

```
    Dim requestURL As String
    requestURL = "https://ABC.com/xyz"
    Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    MyRequest.Open "GET", requestURL
MyRequest.Send
```

Comment: Use a proxy debugger like Fiddler to inspect both requests and look for the differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was with ClearQuest. I was using "&" character in my password and ClearQuest has some different meaning for "&". Due to this it was throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are referencing must be an absolute value. Try changing `requestURL = "example.com/xyz"` to `requestURL = "http://www.example.com/xyz"`.

Comment: I am getting "The server name or address could not be resolved" error if I put  www. Btw my request url contains https.

Comment: Put whatever address you would enter into the browser to access the site including the https into the variable definition and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working and that's why I am looking for solution.

Comment: I missed the part in your question about this working last week and now it is not working. Over the last week, I had an issue where all hyperlinks in Excel and Word to a HTTPS url would give me an error (different one than yours). I found out that it was due in part to not using IE as the default browser on my PC. I also found out that when accessing HTTPS sites from withing Excel and Word they accessing them internally before accessing via the browser. Here is the [MS LB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899927/en-us) that helped me solve my issue. It might solve yours.